# Apple Sign in vs SSO

Tags: ios, single-sign-on

Soon Sign in with Apple would be required for apps that support third-party sign-in.
But I'm not sure - is sign in and Single Sign On (SSO), are the same?
If I'm allowing users to login to my app via SSO, Am I required to allow them login with Apple Sign In?

Comment: What sort of SSO do you offer? Apple Sign In is required if you offer *third-party sign-in*. It's not needed of your company has its own sign-in / single sign-on system.

Comment: I'm using a third party SSO, like Microsoft and OKTA. Not Twitter/facebook/Google

Comment: Can you be more precise? Both Microsoft and Okta have public SaaS, private SaaS and on-premise services. Can a user use the same Microsoft or Okta identity to sign in to your service and to a service unrelated to your company?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. So I'm guessing that this is considered as a public SSO, and I'm required to implement Apple Sign In, right? 
(By the way, you can write it as an answer an I'll mark it as the correct answer)

Comment: In general 'Sign In' and 'SSO' are different. 'Sign In' means 'Authentication' (even if this is kind of automatic like  TLS client auth, Kerberos/SPNEGO, biometric)
SSO means trusting some assertion from an issuing party about an identity.

Comment: So if I'm offering SSO at my app, maybe I won't have to implement Apple Sign In. Hope that's correct.